# Eb harmonic minor scale fingers?

Tags: piano, technique, scales, fingering

Can anyone help me with Eb harmonic minor piano scale fingering, please?
For both hands if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use 2, 3, and 4 on the G♭–A♭–B♭ stretch in the first half of the scale; otherwise you'll use a thumb, pinky, or have to oddly cross over during that stretch of black keys, none of which are ideal.

```
R: 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
L: 2 1 4 3 2 1 3 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it fine to start with the second finger for R.H.? Seems o be more comfortable.

Comment: Sure! The 3 is just to be internally consistent, since you'll use it at the top of the scale. But feel free to start with 2 if that's easier.

Comment: As Richard says. But in the near future you may want to carry on up for another octave. The second octave will start with 3 on Eb. So it **may** be better to learn it now.  Not **2** 1 2 3 4 1 2 **3** 1 2 3 4 1 2 3  but  **3** 1 2 3 4 1 2 **3** 1 2 3 4 1 2 3  But it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks, Richard. I've just found a useful site with the fingering for all major and minor scales, including all the 3 patterns natural, harmonic and melodic.

Comment: https://www.musicteacherguide.com/piano-harmonic-minor-scales/#harmonic

Comment: @ReadyToLearn Wow, that site has the left hand thumb on G♭? That is...unexpected.